# Custom x-axis values in a matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot, axis, octave, figure

Currently when I plot a 9 by 6 array, the x-axis of the figure is just 1, 2, 3 up to 9. The Y-axis shows the correct values.

Instead of 1 to 9 I would like the x-axis values to be custom. They should be

> 100 200 400 1000 2000 5000 10000 20000 50000

instead. I tried

```
set(gca,'XTick', [100 200 400 1000 2000 5000 10000 20000 50000])
```

But that's not the correct way to do it. Is there a `Matlab` option to have these custom values for the x-axis? Why is `Matlab` just using 1 to 9 anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using [xTickLabel](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html#XTickLabel) instead of `XTick`.

MATLAB plots every column as a seperate curve. So, that means you have 6 curves and 9 data points for each curve. x-axis data is 1-9 because you did not provide any data for MATLAB to plot with.

Furthermore, you probably want the wrong thing. Doing this will give you equal spacing. It will just replace 1-9 with your array. Since your x-axis data is not equally spaced, it will be weird.

You may want to do it like this:

```
xdat = [100 200 400 1000 2000 5000 10000 20000 50000];
ydat = rand(9,6); % Your y-axis data
plot(xdat, ydat)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to keep distances between x-values (e.g. 1:9) and only change the labels (not the distances between x-values), try this:

```
y = rand(9,6);
labels = [100 200 400 1000 2000 5000 10000 20000 50000];
plot(y);
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:length(labels)); % Change x-axis ticks
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', labels); % Change x-axis ticks labels.
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
x = [100 200 400 1000 2000 5000 10000 20000 50000];
y = rand(9,6); % Your y-axis data
plot(x, y);
set(gca,'XTick',x); % Change x-axis ticks
set(gca,'XTickLabel',x); % Change x-axis ticks labels to desired values.
```

Please note that due to the very different values/magnitudes to use un x-axis you can get some x-labels very close (and unreadable)

Comment: Is there any way to set set string tick labels? For example, greek letters?